# Problem in my terminal related clamav

Tags: antivirus, clamav

Recently I decided to use Avast Antivirus. I uninstalled clamav and installed Avast. Now whenever I use my terminal I get the following errors.:

```
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,250 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,120 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `clamav-daemon' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `python-pyclamav' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `clamav-base' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `clamav-freshclam' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libclamav6' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `python-clamav' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 554940 files and directories currently installed.)
```

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found the answer.

The reason for the error is that a .list file for the given applications is missing in /var/lib/dpkg/info/. You can either install them again by running

```
sudo apt-get remove <package name>
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install <package name>
```

or you can go for a bit more technical approach by making a new file for each package by running

```
touch <package name>.list
```

For example that would be

```
touch clamav-base.list
```

Source: http://www.vkernel.co.uk/?p=139